# Fetch the size of nested folder from Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 from Databricks notebook

Tags: linux, azure, hadoop, databricks, azure-databricks

**I want fetch folder size details from Databricks Notebook.**

We can do the same via putty by running hadoop fs -lh {root-folder-path}. This command will return human readable size of the all the folder inside root-folder. PFB sample :

[image]

I tried running similar hadoop command from notebook as below but Hadoop is not installed in driver node I believe :

[image]

When I tried ls {root-folder-path}. I am getting folder size as 0. This is because, dbutils provide size value for files only. Folders are hardcoded to 0.PFB sample :

[image]

**Kindly guide me the best way to fetch the details.**

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Databricks, this is expected behavior.

- For Files, it displays the actual file size.
- For Directories, it displays the size=0
- For Corrupted files displays the size=0

[image]

You can get more details using Azure Databricks CLI:

[image]

The following article "[Computing total storage size of a folder in Azure Data Lake with Pyspark](https://medium.com/datalex/computing-total-storage-size-of-a-folder-in-azure-data-lake-with-pyspark-b6ef649f9eca)" explains how to recursively compute the storage size and the number of files and folders in ADLS Gen 1 into Databricks.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: I am unable to test the above steps as I do not have Databricks CLI allowed in our ecosystem. Furthermore, I don't see an example where I get folder size in human readable format through the above Databricks CLI command you have shared. 

I have requested for access and once I try out, will accept your answer.